# Dot product sparse matrices

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sparse-matrix, dot-product

I have two sparse matrices (`a` and `b`) in python of the following dimensions:

```
a = <240760x2177930 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1127853 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

and

```
b = <240760x2177930 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 439309 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

**Question**: I'd like to get a column vector of length 240760 that is the row-wise dot product of the two matrices.  For example, `dot(a[0],b[0])` would be the first element of my output vector. `dot(a[1],b[1])` would be the second, and so forth.

Is there a vectorized easy way to accomplish this?

***EDIT:***  One way to accomplish this would be to convert each row into a dense vector, flatten it out, and use `numpy.dot()`.  Something like:

```
np.dot(np.array(a[0]).flatten(),np.array(b[0]).flatten()).
```

But this requires iterating row wise and convert each row into a dense vector, which is very time consuming.  I'm thinking there's probably an easier way to do this...

Comment: Would this do it: `a.multiply(b).sum(1)`?  It yields a vector of the right length, I'm just not really sure what it's doing.  The whole `csr_matrix` API is so foreign to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `scipy` sparse matrix is modeled on the `numpy` matrix subclass, and as such implements `*` as matrix multiplication.  `a.multiply` is element by element muliplication, such as that used by `np.array` `*`.

I'd suggest making a couple of small matrices, and try the various forms of multiplication, including what you think is the `np.dot` equivalent.  It will be easier to tell what's going on with something small.

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
a1 = sparse.csr_matrix(a)

np.dot(a, a.T)
a1 * a.T
a*a
a1.multiply(a1)
etc
```

Just for reference, is this what you want (using dense arrays):

```
In [7]: a=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

In [8]: [np.dot(a[i],a[i]) for i in range(3)]
Out[8]: [14, 126, 366]

In [9]: np.einsum('ij,ij->i',a,a)
Out[9]: array([ 14, 126, 366])
```

and the sparse

```
In [11]: a1=sparse.csr_matrix(a)
```

The full matrix or dot product is more that what you  want, right?  You just want the diagonal.

```
In [15]: (a1*a1.T).A
Out[15]: 
array([[ 14,  38,  62],
       [ 38, 126, 214],
       [ 62, 214, 366]], dtype=int32)

In [16]: a.dot(a.T)
Out[16]: 
array([[ 14,  38,  62],
       [ 38, 126, 214],
       [ 62, 214, 366]])

In [21]: (a1*a1.T).diagonal()
Out[21]: array([ 14, 126, 366], dtype=int32)
```

For something that is quite sparse taking the full matrix multiplication followed by diagonal might be as fast as any alternative.  Iterating over the rows of a sparse matrix is a relatively slow operation, while the matrix multiplication has been implemented in fast c code.

Another way - element multiplication followed by sum.

```
In [22]: np.sum(a*a,axis=1)
Out[22]: array([ 14, 126, 366])

In [23]: a1.multiply(a1).sum(axis=1)
Out[23]: 
matrix([[ 14],
        [126],
        [366]], dtype=int32)
```

sparse implements `sum` as a matrix multiplication (by a column of ones).

```
In [26]: a1.multiply(a1)*np.array([1,1,1,1])[:,None]
Out[26]: 
array([[ 14],
       [126],
       [366]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Such a great answer. Thank you so much for the different options!